Flaking paint on appliances, is it a child safety issue and what to do if so?
On our oven there's paint flaking off metal (photos below). This is an appliance from the late 90s I think,  been here since before we moved, but it works fine. Someone visiting commented that it is the kind of thing we'd address as part of making the house more child safe, since we're raising an infant.
Is this kind of flaking paint an issue, why or why not? I can see the why being, a kid that can maneuver around the floor briefly unsupervised might eat some of this, intentionally or by getting it on their hands. Maybe getting scraped is an issue with corroded paint/metal flakes, that doesn't seem as likely.
If it is an issue, how to remedy it, assuming this appliance lasts us another few years?



are the flakes soft? ... that might be enamel, which is hard like glass

@jsotola the flakes are not what I'd describe as soft, it is hard but thin and loosened off the rust. Sort of like a rigid tinfoil. Peels off in chips that break free, not super brittle and doesn't produce any dust I see. Is enamel any different than paint in terms of safety in this case?

probably enamel, like the rest of the appliance ... is the metal strip attached to the door? ... maybe it can be removed, repaired and reinstalled

I'll look into replacing/repairing the part. It's attached with hex head screws on the bottom of the door, which I might not be able to de-attach without removing the door. But being an older appliance, thankfully they seem more easily repairable if parts can be obtained.

it may be for holding the glass front

Assuming the front of the oven doesn't get very hot (which would be a child safety issue by itself), a quick and dirty fix would be to cover the metal edge with tape.

It's not a child safety issue in terms of lead paint.  Otherwise, whether a kid eating paint is an issue may be a personal choice.

Eating paint seems bad, lead paint just seems far worse. I guess that's my personal preference and I'll find some way to address this. jpa thanks for seconding the metal tape as a quick fix. If I can't figure out a parts replacement by the time this kid is wandering around, I'll tape it over.

The paint is flaking because the metal it is covering is rusted.
The best course of action is to replace that part with a new one.
If the part cannot be found, you should sand off the rust and repaint so the metal is well covered.  The paint probably does not have lead in it, but the rust is obviously not good and anything falling on a floor will be found by a crawling toddler. Better to correct this asap.  Perhaps cover it with some heavy tape, like duct tape until you can enact a repair.

Ok, I will look for a replacement part. We had to replace its circuit board and that worked fine, hopefully this part is also findable and replaceable.

The only child in the house is just over a month old, so I expect we have many months before they'd crawl into this. If covering with duct tape as a temporary fix, is there any safety issues to be aware of given this is an oven door? (I'll check how hot it gets next time it's on, presumably not super hot.) I imagine you mean metallic duct tape for ductwork, when you suggest taping over it temporarily?

@cr0, Yes I was referring to the aluminium tape. Sorry for not being clear.
